# Send an Array of integers from Processing to Arduino

Tags: arrays, serial-port, processing, arduino-uno

I'm trying to send an Array of 200 integers from Processing to Arduino UNO over the Serial Communication.

I'm sending the integer values using low and high byte.

**For example:**

```
 port.write((int)intArrayValue[i] /256);
 port.write((int)intArrayValue[i] %256);
```

I've also tried to send `(char)` instead of `(int)` with no luck.

However after some time the arduino doesn't read the actual numbers and prints values such as `256,12885 etc.`

On the Arduino side I'm reading the Incoming data as follows:

```
array[i] = Serial.read() * 256+Serial.read();
```

This works for the first 30-35 incoming data. Then incoming data doesn't make any sense.

Do you have any suggestions or any known process of how to pass array of integers (more than 100) from Processing to Arduino. I've tried using many methods found online but none help.

---

Comment: Are you sure you have enough SRAM to store all 200 ints?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've manage to sent 50 ints. Is there any way to clear them and then send another 50?

Comment: You don't need to clear them; just [go back to the beginning of the buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've tried that but it always takes the first 50 values even if I send different array from processing